# modeling composition and expose inner interface

Tags: modeling, composition, uml

I need to model something like this,

ClassA implements interface IClass;

ClassB implements interface IClass;

ClassA has a ClassB (composition);

But the ClassA's interface is the same interface of ClassB, i.e, I need expose the ClassB's interface as the ClassA's interface. I did it in this way,

```
                                 +--------------+
                                 |              |
                        +-------->    IClass    <---------+
                        |        |              |         |
                        |        +--------------+         |<<implements>>
          <<implements>>|                                 |
                        |                                 |
                        |                                 |
                  +-----+-------+                 +-------+-------+
                  |             |+                |               |
                  |   ClassA    +++---------------+    ClassB     |
                  |             |+  <<has a>>     |               |
                  +-------------+                 +---------------+
```

But I'm not sure if this model is correct. How I could improve/fix this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the model I understand this:

```
public class ClassA implements IClass {/* class implementation here */}
public class ClassB implements IClass {
    public ClassA a; //Or private field with getter and setter.
    /* rest of class implementation */
}
```

If this what your code is, then the model is 100% ok.

Additionally (since UML targets to better understanding) if ClassB uses the ClassA field as a helper to implement the IClass interface (by delegating some methods), then you could note that in a UML note.